# не работают команды компиляции ui в py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, командная-строка

Скачал библиотеку pyside6, попытался скомпилировать код ui в py, не получилось "Имя pyside6 не распознано", попытался скомпилировать через pyqt5 и pyqt5-tools, обращаюсь к pyuic, тоже самое, попытался с pyqt6 и pyqt6-tools сделать тоже самое, всё равно не получается, точно так же при выполнении запроса в терминале ошибки, менял много раз версии python(3.4, 3.7, 3.10, 3.11) всё равно не получается. Посмотрел так же нормально ли всё в переменной среды, там есть ли путь к пайтон, есть, удалял и добавлял снова, всё равно не получается скомпилировать, посмотрел много видео разборов ошибок, ни одна не подошла. Много раз удалял и скачивал снова библиотеки все нужные и не нужные, всё попробовал. Как бы ни пытался, ни pyside2, ни pyside6, ни pyuic всех версий, ничего не работает, допустим если pyside6 то ошибка 'Имя "pyside6" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.', и так со всеми методами, ПРОШУ ПОМОГИТЕ, я создал через qt disagner калькулятор, и никак не могу прописать ему логику без компиляции в py, помогите...

Comment: Добавьте Scripts что в папке с установленным питоном в PATH. Если у вас Windows конечно, и советую если плохо разбираетесь как работать с разными версиями пайтона, удалить все кроме той что пользуетесь постоянно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить **PyQt5**, если это не помогает, перейдите по пути:

```
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins
```

(3.9 это моя версия у вас может быть другая) и копируйте из этого пути папку **platforms**. Потом переходите к главной папке питона:

```
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
```

и вставляйте её